# applying read_csv to a Series of filenames only loads the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read-csv

When I run this block of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

working_dir = os.getcwd()+'/'
files = pd.Series(os.listdir(working_dir))

input_files = files[files.str.contains('.csv')]
input_files = working_dir+input_files

dataframes = input_files.apply(pd.read_csv)
```

It returns a series of the same dataframe, the first one I found.

What the?  I have confirmed that all the files have different columns and data in them.

I expect that it returns a Series containing a dataframe for every filename in the original Series that the read_csv had been applied to.

Comment: Could not reproduce. I created 3 CSV files and they were all in `dataframes`/

Comment: Good that you could solve it. Recommend post deletion because not reproducible due to typo?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  The print statement was repeating the same data frame for some reason.  I got it working now.  Thanks everyone for your input.